# Crop Uploaded Image To 1:1 Ratio PHP

Tags: php

I have my own PHP function allowing users to update their profile image.

It all works fine, however, I am having a problem where users can upload any size image they want; i.e: `564 x 346`.

I do not want this to happen. I would like the image that they select to upload to be cropped to a 1:1 ratio and centred; i.e: it goes from `564 x 346` to `346 x 346` and centres to the middle of the image.

None of the scripts that I have found seem to work for my site (at least the way I want them to).

This is the code I am currently using to update their avatar. It consists of checking if they have a correct file extension & if the image is less than 256kb in size:

```
    $ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');
    $file       = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
    $fileext    = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file)));
    $filetmp    = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];

    if(!in_array($fileext, $ext)){
        $errors[] = 'Please select a valid file type. (JPG, JPEG or PNG)';  }
    if($_FILES['avatar']['size'] > 256000){
        $errors[] = 'Avatars cannot exceed a 256kb file size.';
    }

    if(empty($errors)){
        updateAvatar($conn, $username, $filetmp, $fileext);
    } else if(!empty($errors)){
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['updateAvat'])){
        flash('You have successfully updated your avatar.');
        unset($_SESSION['updateAvat']);
    }
```

This is the `updateAvatar()` function that I have made and is called on line 13:

```
function updateAvatar($conn, $username, $filetmp, $fileext){
    $file = md5(microtime() . $filetmp) . '.' . $fileext;
    $filepth = './data/user_data/img/udid/prof/' . $file;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepth);
    if(mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET profile = '$file' WHERE username = '$username'")){
        $_SESSION['updateAvat'] = md5(microtime() . $filetmp);
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'There was a problem updating your avatar. Please try again.';
    }
}
```

However, this is not enough and does not allow my users profile page to work or look the way it should, I am going for something along the lines of how Google or Twitter do their avatar's.

All help is appreciated.
Cheers.

Comment: Have you considered leaving the image as is, but rendering it in `<div style="background: transparent url('/path/to/avatar.ext') no-repeat scroll center center; background-size: cover;"></div>`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol hi, this would work, however, my CSS is styled a bit differently to the norm and would still look weird. ahah

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol would be easier just to resize like every other website

Comment: all I see is file handling and error checking - where's the code you use for cropping?

Comment: @Joni the cropping scripts that I tried never worked the way they should, therefore, I didn't include them.

Comment: Always include what you've tried in the question. For example, if you have the imagick extension you can crop and resize with a single function call. No need to checking image sizes, aspect ratios etc

Comment: @Joni sorry, will do next time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `imagecrop()` function in php:

```
$tmpfile = $_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'];

switch ($fileext) {
 case 'jpg':
 case 'jpeg':
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpfile);
   break;
 case 'png':
   $image = imagecreatefrompng($tmpfile);
   break;
 default:
   die("wtf is this extension??");
}

list($w, $h) = getimagesize($imgfile);
// get width $w and height $h for the image

if ($w < $h) // then keep the width and scale the height
 $image = imagecrop($image, array(
                              "x" => 0,
                              "y" => ($h - $w) / 2,
                              "width" => $w,
                              "height" => $w
                              ));
else if ($h < $w) // then keep the height and scale the width
 $image = imagecrop($image, array(
                              "x" => ($w - $h) / 2,
                              "y" => 0,
                              "width" => $h,
                              "height" => $h
                              ));
```

I haven't tried this code but I'm quite sure it's right. Try it and tell me if it doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**
Then you can save the resource `$image` with `imagejpeg()` or `imagepng()` to save the images with the same extensions so you won't have problems with the database:

```
imagejpeg($image, "/path/to/your/image.jpg");
```

Comment: I'll test this out. But I cannot believe this existed! aha, cheers for the answer and explaining it through the comments :)

Comment: How would I make it so that this works for JPEG, JPG & PNG? Cheers.

Comment: In the code you've posted you extracted the extension, `switch` it and use it as I explained in line 3 of my code

Comment: if I switch it, it'll still only function for one extension.

do you think you could update your code?

Comment: updated. This is what I meant. The image resource php holds into the RAM is the cross-extension

Comment: ok cheers. now it makes sense! I'll try it now, I didn't even know what the switch function was.. :/

Comment: `switch` is a C-based structure. It's really basic programming I'm quite impressed you're developing a website like that and you don't know the multi-selection statement lol

Comment: Worked perfectly! Cheers dude, couldn't have done it without you! :)

Answer (score 0):

> This is an explanation of how the process works, this is not a copy
>   and paste code but a description of the logic processes you need to
>   understand to resize images in PHP

You want to be using PHP [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) to take the original image and then work out mathematically the margins to make it a square and then resize that square.

Process:

- Uploaded image is checked is a genuine image and genuine filetype.
- Using [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) (or similar ones for PNG etc.) you can import the uploaded image file resource.
- Using [`getimagesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) you can find the dimensions, you can then find [the aspect ratio of the image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180804/how-to-get-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image).
- If the aspect ratio is > 1 then width is larger than height so you then need to assume a square the same size as height (as it's the smaller value). For example:

.

```
 Width: 450
 Height: 300
 Ratio = 450/300 = 3/2 = 1.5 = >1
```

- If the aspect ratio is <1 then the height is larger than the width.
- So you want a square that is 300x300 so you need to cut off the excess 150 from the width. This is called the *Margin*, and to centre the image you need to cut off half of the margin from each side so:

.

```
$fullMargin = (width- height) 
$margin = $fullMargin/2
```

- Just before resizing and saving the new image, a new image resource should be generated:

.

```
$max_width = $max_height = 256;
$smallestDimensionValue = $originalHeight //(in this example);
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width,$max_height);
$sourceHeight = $originalHeight;
$sourceWidth = $originalWidth - $fullMargin;
```

- Finally, Image copy and resample and the output should be as intended:

.

```
 imagecopyresampled($nwImage, $sourceImage, 0,0,$margin,0,$max_width,$max_height,$sourceWidth,$sourceHeight);
```

---

- PHP scales the image in the `imagecopyresampled` automatically, but to understand it, Once you've established the Margin size for the full size image you then have to multiply the margin by the same value as the width and the height to scale the overall image to the appropriate size.

Say for example you want the avatar to have a maximum size of 256px then:

```
 maximum_allowed_width /  original_width = scale_factor.
```

So for the example above this is:

```
256 / 450 = 0.56888888
```

This is the value the margin value defined above, as well as the height and width of the destination image, is multiplied by.

Comment: cheers for the answer, however, I didn't really get it... Try simplifying it a bit or putting it into my function? So I can understand what Is going on.

Comment: What parts do you not get? What confuses?